# MVC 3 - Ninject - Membership - SQL Server Express 2008 r2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, sql-server-express, custom-membershipprovider

Here is my setup:

I have modeled my application after the SportsStore in Pro ASP.NET MVC3 Framework book.

For those that don't have the book:

I have 2 projects bundled in a solution -

```
--Project.Domain--

  Abstract(folder)
  ..IObjectRepository.cs

  Concrete(folder)
  ..EFObjectRepository.cs

  Entities(folder)
  ..Data.cs - contains class definition for Object

--Project.WebUI--

  Areas(folder)
  ..Area1
  ..Area2

  Infrastructure(folder)
  ..NinjectControllerFactory.cs
```

My question is how do I organize a custom membership provider with Ninject, with the way my app is currently structured?

Please provide code in C# and explain where each file should exist in my structure.

Please also provide all methods for account creation within the `CustomMembershipProvider`.

If you would like any additional info please let me know.

Thanks in advance for preventing insanity.

Comment: The SportsStore uses a IAuthProvider in the AccountController to decouple your controller from the FormsAuthentication. Can you use that or do you want to do something else?

Comment: I guess I can use that. Btw, thanks for heads up on acceptance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to supply your own implementation of `IAuthProvider` you need to do the following:

- Add your custom class to SportsStore.WebUI\Infrastructure\Concrete and let it inherit from `IAuthProvider`

  public class MyCustomAuthProvider : IAuthProvider
  {
      public bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
      {
          // Implement this function with your custom logic
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
  }
- In the NinjectControllerFactory change the binding:

Change

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IAuthProvider>().To<FormsAuthProvider>();
```

To

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IAuthProvider>().To<MyCustomAuthProvider>();
```

This will change your dependency injection. The AccountController will now use your custom implementation.

Comment: I have done that but I am getting an error with 
Views > Shared > _LogonPartial

Also - how to I change the Register() Method in the AccountController to work with DI?